# EF Core first call is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Environment: .NET 6 / EF Core 6 with main lazy-loaded DbContext having ~30 entities. (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

I’m having a problem that once I run WebAPI project, the first simple call that uses EF Core usually takes 4-8 seconds to execute. After that, cold endpoints with EF go to acceptable hundreds range millisecond.

I observed with fresh projects the first EF call (context has 1 entity) also has eye noticable delay compared to light ORM like Dapper.

I’m aware than on first context query the dbContext model is built and stored in memory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#2-cold-vs-warm-query-execution.

Hot-reload on VS helps but it would be cool to shave this time in development on restarts and improve initial responsiveness after API deployment. I also bootstrap it with SPA so after my SPA is loaded I have to wait additional time for API to respond. Thinking I could kickstart it while SPA is building, I tried adding in startup.cs (from pre-.NET 6 starting template) in Configure method

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    using var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
    var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
    _ = dbContext.Model;
}
```

It makes an improvement to first call making it 2-4 seconds but it’s still not on par with calls made after first call (assuming this code forces caching the dbContext). Also, having this section I believe makes my API project start slower by few seconds (no benchmarking, just Google's stopwatch) so there appears to be no gain if not increasing the time.

I’m aware that EF Core 6 has https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#compiled-models but my project uses lazy loading so it won’t work:

```
The entity type 'AccessRights' has a custom constructor binding. This is usually caused by using proxies. Compiled model can't be generated, because dynamic proxy types are not supported. If you are not using proxies configure the custom constructor binding in 'Customize()' in a partial 'RightsEntityType' class instead.
```

Plenty of threads on this topic predates EF Core / .NET Core and I didn't find clear solutions. Maybe there are some solutions for my case?

Edit1: seems like this method is improvement overall when moved to the end for development environment. In bootstrapping project that combines API + SPA I can call it after starting SPA so while SPA is loading behind the scenes dbContext.Model can build some model details to speed up real queries. Calling real entity to make call to SQL improves first call further (yet still far to real 2nd call speed) but it requires DB being responsive for app to even start. In regular WebApi with Swagger UI it also starts building model details while Swagger UI is still loading. I'll use it.

On deployment server then it would need to be ensured that the app auto starts running and doesn't wait for the first user visit to the app.

Comment: Why not just call ` _ = dbContext.Model;`.  Reason to use `Task.Run` here?

Comment: You may consider posting on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Original idea was to let it spin without awaiting and move to setting up SPA but I left sections from that attempt. I can move this code in bootstrapped project after SPA creation (app.UseSpa()) in development so while the SPA loads behind the scenes it could start building model. When I call dbContext.entity.FirstOrDefault() it seems first response is quicker but that requires DB working during Configure() run so I'll stay with dbContext.Model. On sole API project then it's trade-off if to take longer startup or longer first call (assuming after deployment app starts running).

Comment: EF Core compiles the LINQ expression the first time it's called, and caches it for later use. So, that's why the first time is slower.